# Iterate through alphabet using send.key on selenium to scrape info

Tags: selenium

Right now my code is set up to scrape through all the last names that start with 'Z'

```
 query = ['Z']
 for letter in query:
    url = "https://hsba.org/HSBA_2020/For_the_Public/Find_a_Lawyer/HSBA_2020/Public/Find_a_Lawyer.aspx"
    driver.get(url)
    #input from query 
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#txtDirectorySearchLastName')
    element.send_keys(letter)
```

I need it to loop through the whole alphabet and get all the text info on each page.

I tried searching for help and am not sure where to start...
(Disclaimer: very new to coding)

Comment: If you want the tables on each page you could read them  with pandas with .read_html() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
alphabets=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
for alph in alphabets:
    url = "https://hsba.org/HSBA_2020/For_the_Public/Find_a_Lawyer/HSBA_2020/Public/Find_a_Lawyer.aspx"
    driver.get(url)
    #input from query 
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#txtDirectorySearchLastName')
    element.send_keys(alph)
```

If you need to loop all the letters just get all letters using string.ascii_lowercase and loop them.

Comment: _`string.ascii_lowercase`_ niche idea !!!

Comment: There are so many ways to do this lol.